# Mapas dinâmicos no Google Maps

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Tenho um sistema onde pessoas colocam os respectivos endereços.
Gostaria de saber como pegar, um endereço e fazer aparecer no maps. Entendem? Cada pessoa no sistema terá uma página onde aparecerá um mapa com uma marca no local onde a pessoa mora.

Valeu pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem sim, e são basicamente dois passos, o primeiro é o de obter as coordenadas geograficas do endereço, para isto você pode utilizar um serviço de geolocalização do proprio google, você pode saber mais neste endereço: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=pt-br

Com as coordenadas do endereço em mãos, basta adicionar um novo marcador ao mapa.

Caso o mapa possua muitos marcadores, eu recomendo você utilizar o serviço de geolocalização para pegar os dados e salvar eles em banco, pois utilizar o serviço todas as vezes que for exibir um endereço fica custoso.

Comment: não vou colocar mais de uma marca em um mapa só. Cada perfil de usuário terá um único mapa com uma marca

Comment: eu entendi praticamente tudo, só não entendi como exibir os dados em formato json no google maps, entendeu?

Comment: Você vai utilizar os valores de latitude e longitude retornados na chave localiton em geometry, algo mais ou menos results[0].geometry.location.lat e results[0].geometry.location.lng. Você utiliza esses valores para criar os marcadores.

Comment: isso eu entendi, mas em que formato devo usar esses valores? No formato json e colocado direto dentro do script ou passo os valores por parâmetro? Não peguei como fazer a sintáxe.

Comment: Aqui tem um link com um exemplo do uso da API e de como utilizar resultado da consulta. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple?hl=pt-br

Comment: para facilitar o meu trabalho de pegar um endereço, enviar para o site que converte em coordenadas e fazer as coordenadas retornarem para os códigos que geram o mapa, eu resolvi copiar todo o site que gera as coordenadas. Porém, quero que o site gere as coordenadas, sem precisar clicar no botão Serach da página, como eu poderia fazer isso?
Falo desse site http://universimmedia.pagesperso-orange.fr/geo/loc.htm

Comment: Pessoal, to tentando colocar essa div, mas ela não aparece não minha página.
Tem algum problema se a página for em php?
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px; height:380px;"></div>